# Redirect to a particular viewcontroller when redirecting from reset password mail ios

Tags: ios, url-scheme

In my app I have a Home viewcontroller from where user can login, reset password, and skip to other pages.

If I click "Forgot password", I will get a mail where I can reset password. When I redirect back from email, I want the app to stay in the same Home viewcontroller.

If my flow is : click on "Forgot password" from home viewcontroller -> then move to ForgotPassword viewcontrollers -> exit app -> then go to my mail and do reset password , even then I want the app to open in the home page itself when it comes to foreground, not on any other viewcontrollers from where I exited the app or minimised the app.

How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: I'm assuming you have URL-scheme set up for navigating back to the app from the mail in which case use the URL-scheme to navigate to the home screen by having something. `yourapp-scheme://home` if you are unfamiliar with URL schemes in the iOS app then I suggest you read about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by manage flag after change password and go app on background.

Let me explain, In the AppDelegate take one global `var isChangedPwd = false`. When end use will go on reset password screen and successfully reset password then you need to make `isChangedPwd = true` and then manage flag in `applicationDidEnterBackground` like below

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
     if isChangedPwd {
        exit(0)
     }
}
```

It means when your `isChangedPwd` will be **true** and App will goes in background then your app will exit and will be launch at initial level.

**NOTE :** If you don't want to use **exit(0)** and not start app at initial level then you can redirect to **Home page** by below code.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
         if isChangedPwd {
            for viewCon in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
              if viewCon is HomePageViewController {
                self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewCon, animated: true)
                break
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that is a great user experience to terminate the app instead of managing the user navigation. Its a workaround rather a good solution

Comment: @carbonr Yes you are right  I'm thinking same thats why I updated with second solution.

Comment: @vensM Good then you can accept my answer so any other developer , whom facing same question will help-full too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question:
You want that whenever user taps on "Forgot password" on HomeScreen, user will be directed to ForgotPasswordScreen and then user receive a mail(with a link to reset the password [all these done by your server]). Coming back to app, user should be shown HomeScreen, whether its launching the app or already at background.

If above is the scenario then I guess there is an extra task that you are performing.

I would suggest that there is no need of ForgotPasswordScreen, just show an alert with a textfield to let user enter the email id to send password reset mail to it.

And you should just set one flag **isLoggedIn**

If **isLoggedIn == true** only then load your other viewControllers.

**isLoggedIn** has to be a global variable which should be set only at the time of successful login/logout